# Webservice Endpoint - can someone externally scan all services available on a host?

Tags: web-services, security, web-applications, dns, jboss7.x

Say we have hosted a few webservices over over https://mycompany.com/Service
e.g.
https://mycompany.com/Service/Service1
https://mycompany.com/Service/Service2
https://mycompany.com/Service/Service3

As you can see on mycompany.com we have hosted 3 webservices each having their distinct urls.
What we have is a Jboss instance with 3 different web wars deployed in it. When someone hits the service it gets past our firewall and then teh load balancer redirects to Jboss on port 8080 on the requried path and it gets serviced.

the 3 services are consumed by 3 different clients. My question if say Client1 using Service 1 is only given out the url corresponding to it can they use some kind of scanner that can also inform them that Service2 and Service3 are alaso available on mycompany.com/Service?

Irrespective of clients - can anyone simply use some scanner tool to identify what Service Endpoints are exposed on the host? 
Kindly note they are a mix of SOAP (WSDL) and Rest based services deployed on same instance of Jboss.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, someone can scan for those endpoints. Their scanner would generate a bunch of 404s in your logs, because it would have to guess the other URLs. If you have some kind of rate limiting firewall, it might take them quite a long time. You should be checking the logs regularly anyway.

If you expose your URL to the public internet, relying on people not finding it is just security via obscurity. You should secure each URL using application-level security, and *assume* that the bad guys already have the URL.

You may want to consider adding subdomains for the separate applications (e.g. service1.mycompany.com, service2.mycompany.com) - this will make firewalling easier.